# Searchkick Elastic Search where condition like behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, ruby-on-rails-4.2, searchkick

Using Rails 4.2 with searchkick and elasticsearch, we have some where conditions set up to find users:

```
where_data = {
  region: "North America"
}
results = Person.search( query, where: where_data )
```

This works as expected and finds a person when `Person.region` is "North America".

But there are other situations where the person has multiple regions, including North America:  "Africa; North America".  In these cases the person is not found.

How can I customize the where data or calls so that it will operate more like `LIKE` in sql, and find any matching instances of the full string?

Comment: Can you paste your indexed data ?

I think you need to index those all regions also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To search for a Person where region contains "North America", first try:

```
Person.search "North America", fields: [:region]
```

If that doesn't work, try adding this to the Person Model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  searchkick word_middle: [:region]
```

And then (after you reindex)

```
Person.search "North America", fields: [:region], match: :word_middle
```

If that still doesn't work, I would suggest making `:region` a collection in ES (please let me know if you are interested, I have done this before using searchkick but don't recall the exact code.  I can pull it up and post for you later)

Comment: Thanks Jim, I tried adding the `word_middle` to searchkick but it didn't work.  The search text `query` is already set, and now trying to filter the results based on the selected region.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass instead of a hash an array.
So you can have:

```
where_data = [
  "region LIKE North America"
]
results = Person.search( query, where: where_data )
```

This way the where clause will use LIKE to look up for your results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Searchkik but I am a daily elastic user. I would think that if you submitted a space delimited string of the region options it would match them all.

```
option_string  = array_of_options.join(" ")
```

Using the JSON syntax with elasticsearch-rails gems you should be able to achieve this.

```
where_data = {
  region: option_string
}
results = Person.search( query, where: where_data )
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the info.  I am just trying to filter on a single string.  The column has one or more options in it.